# Visualizing the Free Monad

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad

I think I have rough idea of what the free monad is, but I would like to have a better way to visualize it.

It makes sense that free magmas are just binary trees because that's as "general" as you can be without losing any information.

Similarly, it makes sense that free monoids are just lists, because the order of operations doesn't matter. There is now a redundancy in the "binary tree", so you can just flatten it, if that makes sense.

It makes sense that free groups kind of look like fractals, for a similar reason: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph#/media/File:Cayley_graph_of_F2.svg
and to get other groups, we just identify different elements of the group as being the "same" and we get other groups.

How should I be visualizing the free monad? Right now, I just think of it as the most general abstract syntax tree that you can imagine. Is that essentially it? Or am I oversimplifying it?

Also, similarly, what do we lose in going from a free monad to a list or other monads? What are we identifying to be the "same"?

I appreciate all comments that shed light into this. Thanks!

Comment: A bunch of functors in a chain? That's basically it... I've always seen it as a kind of nested box of functors that you push others along. The features of the functor itself could make it a tree or fractal-like structure, but on a type level, that's not relevant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Right now, I just think of [the free monad] as the most general abstract syntax tree that you can imagine. Is that essentially it? Or am I oversimplifying it?

You're oversimplifying it:

1. "Free monad" is short for "the free monad **over a specific functor**" or the `Free f a` data type, which in reality is a different free monad for each choice of `f`.
2. There is no one general structure that all free monads have.  Their structure breaks down into:

   - What is contributed by `Free` itself
   - What is contributed by different choices for `f`

But let's take a different approach.  I learned free monads by first studying the closely related [operational monad](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/operational-monad.html) instead, which has a more uniform, easier-to-visualize structure.  I highly recommend you study that from the link itself.

The simplest way to define the operational monad is like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Program instr a where
  Return :: a -> Program instr a
  Bind :: instr x                  -- an "instruction" with result type `x`
       -> (x -> Program instr a)   -- function that computes rest of program
       -> Program instr a          -- a program with result type `a`
```

...where the `instr` type parameter represents the "instruction" type of the monad, usually a GADT.  For example (taken from the link):

```
data StackInstruction a where
    Pop  :: StackInstruction Int
    Push :: Int -> StackInstruction ()
```

So a `Program` in the operational monad, informally, I'd visualize it as a "dynamic list" of instructions, where the result produced by the execution of any instruction is used as input to the function that decides what the "tail" of the "instruction list" is.  The `Bind` constructor pairs an instruction with a "tail chooser" function.

Many free monads can also be visualized in similar terms—you can say that the functor chosen for a given a free monad serves as its "instruction set."  But with free monads the "tails" or "children" of the "instruction" are managed by the `Functor` itself.  So a simple example (taken from [Gabriella González's popular blog entry on the topic](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html)):

```
data Free f r = Free (f (Free f r)) | Pure r

-- The `next` parameter represents the "tails" of the computation.
data Toy b next =
    Output b next
  | Bell next
  | Done

instance Functor (Toy b) where
  fmap f (Output b next) = Output b (f next)
  fmap f (Bell next) = Bell (f next)
  fmap _ Done = Done
```

While in the operational monad the function used to generate the "tail" belongs to the `Program` type (in the `Bind` constructor), in free monads the tails belong to the "instruction"/`Functor` type.  This allows the free monad's "instructions" (an analogy that is now breaking down) to have a single "tail" (like `Output` or `Bell`), zero tails (like `Done`) or multiple tails if you so chose to.  Or, in another common pattern, the `next` parameter can be the result type of an embedded function:

```
data Terminal a next = 
    PutStrLn String next
  | GetLine (String -> next)  -- can't access the next "instruction" unless
                              -- you supply a `String`.

instance Functor Terminal where
    fmap f (PutStrLn str next) = PutStrLn str (f next)
    fmap f (GetLine g) = GetLine (fmap f g)
```

This, incidentally, is an objection I've long had to people who refer to free or operational monads as "syntax trees"—practical use of them requires that "children" of a node be opaquely hidden inside a function.  You generally can't fully inspect this "tree"!

So really, when you get down to it, how to visualize a free monad comes down entirely to the structure of whichever `Functor` that you use to parametrize it.  Some look like lists, some look like trees, and some look like "opaque trees" with functions as nodes.  (Somebody once responded to my objection above with a line like "a function is a tree node with as many children as there are possible arguments.")

Answer (score 2):

You may have heard

> Monad is a monoid in a category of endofunctors

And you mentioned already that monoids are just lists. So there you are.

---

Expanding on that a bit:

```
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Free (f (Free f a))
```

It's not a normal list of `a`, but a list where tail is wrapped inside `f`. You'll see it if you write a structure of value of multiple nested binds:

```
pure x >>= f >>= g >>= h :: Free m a
```

might result into

```
Free $ m1 $ Free $ m2 $ Free $ m3 $ Pure x
  where m1, m2, m3 :: a -> m a -- Some underlying functor "constructors"
```

If `m` in example above is sum type:

```
data Sum a = Inl a | Inr a
  deriving Functor
```

Then the list is actually a tree, as at each constructor we can branch left or right.

---

You may have heard that

> Applicative is a monoid in a category of endofunctors

... the category is just different. There are nice visualisations of different free applicative encodings in [Roman Cheplyaka's blog post](https://ro-che.info/articles/2013-03-31-flavours-of-free-applicative-functors).

So free `Applicative` is also a list. I imagine it as a heterogenous list of `f a` values, and single function:

```
 x :: FreeA f a
 x = FreeA g [ s, t, u, v]
    where g :: b -> c -> d -> e -> a
          s :: f b
          t :: f c
          u :: f d
          v :: f e
```

In this case the the tail itself isn't wrapped in `f`, but each element separately. This might or might not help understand the difference between `Applicative` and `Monad`.

Note, that `f` doesn't need to be `Functor` to make `Applicative (FreeA f a)`, controrary to `Free` monad above.

---

There is also free `Functor`

```
data Coyoneda f a = Coyoneda :: (b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a
```

which makes any `* -> *` type `Functor`. Compare it with free `Applicative` above.
In applicative case we had a heterogenous list of length *n* of `f a` values and a n-ary function combining them.
Coyoneda is 1-ary special case of above.

---

We can combine `Coyoneda` and `Free` to make `Operational` free monad. And as other answer mentions, that one is hardy imaginable as tree, as there is functions involved. OTOH you can imagine those continuations as different, magical arrows in your picture :)